# problem to update ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, updates, update-manager, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

When trying to update Ubuntu, I receive the following failed error message.

```
W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone could help me to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to me the PPA does not exist anymore. I do not know this particular one, but a quick google on "ppa sevenmachines" turned up some stuff. As that PPA seems to be used for Flash (only?), one of them notes this:

I quote:
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

After removing flashplugin64-installer (and removing the sevenmachines ppa from my sources), then just selecting linux 64 bit and ubuntu in the above link. It asked me if i'd like to add the partner repository, followd by the question to install the flash package from adobe. It seems to be up to date for lucid (version 11,1,102,55) and working rather well (for me)."

Something similar should work for you, I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I unchecked these items on the update-manager. Then, followed the instructions. Update is working again and flash is working on G.Chrome.